# Typing React Props with variants

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typing

I'm working on a React Ts  Header that has some variants.
the Header Component has two variants Named `HomeHeader` and `DefaultHeader`
Here only the DefaultHeader needs a required prop `title` whereas HomeHeader doesn't.

now how to type the HeaderProps HomeHeaderProps and DefaultHeaderProps

the current implementation (not perfect)

```
interface HeaderProps {
  variant?: "DEFAULT" | "HOME";
  classes?: string;
  title?: string;
};

variant VariantHeaderProps {
   classes?: string;
   title?: string
};
```

and are used as

```
const Header: FC<HeaderProps> = ({ variant = "DEFAULT", classes, title })

const DefaultHeader: FC<VariantHeaderProps> = ({ classes, title })

const HomeHeader: FC<VariantHeaderProps> = ({ classes })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend a new interface from the `HeaderProps` and override the `title` definition to be a required property like so.

```js
interface DefaultHeaderProps extends HeaderProps {
  title: string;
};
```

And declare `DefaultHeader` with it:

```js
const DefaultHeader: FC<DefaultHeaderProps> = ({ classes, title })
```

To make `{ variant: "DEFAULT", classes, title }` also strict do the following by using [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```js
interface StrictDefaultHeaderProps {
  variant: "DEFAULT";
  classes?: string;
  title: string;
}

interface StrictHomeHeaderProps {
  variant: "HOME";
  classes?: string;
  title?: string;
}

type StrictHeaderProps = StrictDefaultHeaderProps | StrictHomeHeaderProps

const Header: FC<StrictHeaderProps> = ({ variant = "DEFAULT", classes, title })
```

Comment: `@CodeMoreTestTest`

Comment: Works fine but the type checking in the Header Component is not strict, is there any way to make the title prop required if the type="DEFAULT" and is not when the same is of "HOME"

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I've edited the answer with the solution for this case also.